# Need help in understanding torque and Spring Force

Tags: mechanical-engineering, torque, springs

I have another question for the smart people on here!! I am working on a project and I need a better understanding of the forces.

I have a torque applied from a torque driver of 0.7 Nm to screw down a nut onto a threaded shaft. This nut then applies a force down onto a stainless steel place that has a spring attached. The spring sits in a housing (that spins) around a stationary housing. There is a friction disk that is between the two housings to provide friction. I'm able to measure the torque of the spinning housing to stationary housing to be around 0.7 Nm. It's kinda like a simplified clutch design in the sense that I have a spring, friction plate, and it rotates around a stationary housing. So, I know the torque applied to the nut (0.7 Nm) and I know the torque output of the clutch (0.7 Nm). How do I know how much force is from the spring? I know the coefficient of friction between the spinning housing and the stationary housing too. It's 0.27.

Here is what I kinda calculated. The clamp force from nut is Torque = K X D (bolt diameter) X Force. I'm assuming K=0.2 and the bolt diameter is 0.00127 (meters). So Force transmitted through the SS washer is ~550 N.

I know clutch torque...it's 0.7 Nm. From T = Ftotal X R. I assumed Ftotal = Fspring x coefficient of friction. From this formula - 0.7 Nm/ (0.27 * 0.0245 / 2) = 211 N. So F spring = 211 N.

Does this sound right? Is there a relationship between torque of the nut and torque of the clutch? I just want to make sure I'm calculating this right.

Thanks[image]